# Oracle SQL: Missing identifier error in Select with Xmlagg

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, concatenation, aggregation

I am new to Oracle and hope someone here can help me with this.

I have a Select that returns the following without row aggregation:
[current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eR5cg.jpg)

My problem here is that I can have multiple rows for certain IDs in the first column whereas **I need just one row per ID, like this**:
[required output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YRfi.jpg)

`Select Distinct` is not an option in my case and `Listag` doesn't allow enough characters for the second column.

After some research I think Xmlagg is exactly what I need here but I cannot get this to work and always get an error here so I think I am writing it wrong.

**Latest error:**

```
ORA-00931: missing identifier
```

Can someone show me how to write this properly ?

**My query (shortened):**

```
ALTER SESSION ENABLE PARALLEL QUERY;
SELECT
    a.Id
    , RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT("Details", 
        (
            b.title || ' -' || c.item || ' -' || b.quantity) ORDER BY b.title)
        ).EXTRACT('//text()'), ' --- ') AS Details
    , TO_CHAR(c.total, 'FM9,990.00') AS Sum
FROM 
    table1 d
/* joins */
WHERE
/* ... */
GROUP BY
    a.Id
    , b.title
    , c.item
    , b.quantity
ORDER BY
    a.Id
```

Many thanks in advance.
Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a few things need to be moved here and there.

```
SELECT a.Id ,
    RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT("Details", b.title
    || ' -'
    || c.item
    || ' -'
    || b.quantity ,' --- ' ).EXTRACT('//text()')
ORDER BY b.title),
    ' --- ')
AS
    Details , TO_CHAR(c.total, 'FM9,990.00')
AS
    SUM FROM table1 d
    /* joins */
    WHERE 
* ... */
GROUP BY
    a.Id
    , b.title
    , c.item
    , b.quantity
ORDER BY
    a.Id
```

Comment: Thanks, Sudipta. It doesn't look like this is what I need here. You can ignore the sum as I can pull this from a separate table so it doesn't have to be calculated. Most important for me is to combine the columns for "Details" but this is both text and numbers so it seems wrong to me here.

Comment: @keewee279 - Do you get any errors, when you are running it ? Not sure, about what you mean, when you say **but this is both text and numbers so it seems wrong to me here**